# How to force data type return when querying excel from Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, oledb

I'm using `Powershell` to query an excel spreadsheet using an OLEDB connection.  I have one column with multiple values in it.  I have noticed that when 1 our of the 4 cells contains letters, the query will return a `NULL` and the data type will be a `System.DBNull`.  See below:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet 1]

Script output:

```
PS D:\temp> D:\WCC_Powershell\ExcelTypeTest.ps1 test.xls
Ticket Number: 1 | Type: System.Double
Ticket Number: 2 | Type: System.Double
Ticket Number:  | Type: System.DBNull
Ticket Number: 4 | Type: System.Double
```

However if 2 of the 4 cells contain letters, all cell data types come back as `String`.  Example:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet 2]

Script output:

```
PS D:\temp> D:\WCC_Powershell\ExcelTypeTest.ps1 test.xls
Ticket Number: 1 | Type: System.String
Ticket Number: ZZZZ | Type: System.String
Ticket Number: AAAA | Type: System.String
Ticket Number: 4 | Type: System.String
```

Is there a way force the return type of a Excel column when querying from Powershell?  My script needs to know if 1) there is data there (not return a NULL) and 2) Know the data type

Here is the script Im using to parse the excel document:

```
########################################################################################################
# This function will test if a string value is numeric
# Parameters:
#   $value   - String to test
########################################################################################################
function IsNumeric($value) {
   return ($($value.Trim()) -match "^[-]?[0-9.]+$")
}

########################################################################################################
# This filter will test if a string value is numeric
# Parameters:
#   $value   - String to test
########################################################################################################
filter isNumeric2() {
    return $_ -is [byte]  -or $_ -is [int16]  -or $_ -is [int32]  -or $_ -is [int64]  `
       -or $_ -is [sbyte] -or $_ -is [uint16] -or $_ -is [uint32] -or $_ -is [uint64] `
       -or $_ -is [float] -or $_ -is [double] -or $_ -is [decimal]
}

# Directory location where we have our excel files
########################################################################################################
$excelFN = "$args"
$ExcelFile = "D:\Temp\$excelFN"
$Sheetname = "Interface$"

########################################################################################################
$OleDbConn = New-Object “System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection”
$OleDbCmd = New-Object “System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand”
$OleDbAdapter = New-Object “System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter”
$DataTable = New-Object “System.Data.DataTable”
$OleDbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$ExcelFile`";Extended Properties=`"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES`";"
$OleDbConn.Open()
$OleDbCmd.Connection = $OleDbConn
$OleDbCmd.commandtext = “Select * from [$Sheetname]”
$OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand = $OleDbCmd
########################################################################################################

$RowsReturned = $OleDbAdapter.Fill($DataTable)
$intRow = 1
ForEach ($DataRec in $DataTable) {

    # Reading the first column of the current row
    $TicketNumber = $DataRec."ticket number"

    write-host "Ticket Number:" $TicketNumber "| Type:" $TicketNumber.GetType()

    $intRow++
}

$OleDbConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257819) (emphasis added):

> **A Caution about Mixed Data Types**
>
> As stated previously, ADO must guess at the data type for each column
>   in your Excel worksheet or range. (This is not affected by Excel cell
>   formatting settings.) A serious problem can arise if you have numeric
>   values mixed with text values in the same column. Both the Jet and the
>   ODBC Provider ***return the data of the majority type, but return NULL
>   (empty) values for the minority data type.*** If the two types are
>   equally mixed in the column, the provider chooses numeric over text.

The "safe" option is to treat all fields as text, by adding an `IMEX=1` option to the connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$ExcelFile`";Extended Properties=`"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1`";"
```

and then convert numeric values in your PowerShell script, either using explicit casts such as:

```
[int]$value
# or
$value -as [int]
```

Soft coercion with a unary operator such as:

```
+$value
```

or using static parsing like this:

```
[int]::Parse($value)
# or
$numericValue = 0
[int]::TryParse($value,[ref]$numericValue)
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly the issue.  However it looks like I might still be stuck, if I use the IMEX=1, but the first 8 rows (based on [this registry setting TypeGuessRows=8](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194124/en-us)) are numeric it will not return `text`.  But at least I now know what the issue is, appreciate the input.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur The other article mentions a registry setting ImportMixedTypes=Text under the same key, maybe that helps?

Comment: Yes that was already set to text.  The IMEX=1 works great if the first 8 rows or so are actually text.  The issue I have is I never know how many rows of data I'm going to process and I dont have control over the data type because a third party sends it to me.  So the solution does work, I just can't be sure how many rows will be numeric or text in the excel file.  I do appreciate the help and am amazed you found a KB article on it so quickly!